# How can I put the package.json file and the public folder inside anoter folder in a React App and make it works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I created a react app and I got this structure in my project:

```
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
```

I started to add components and create the App, but now my team wants me to change the structure and put the public folder and the Package.json inside another folder, let's call the folder "example". I change the structure like that:

```
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── .gitignore
├── example
│   ├── package.json
│   └── public
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── index.html
│       └── manifest.json
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
```

Now the App does not work when I use `npm start` (I expected that) and now I don´t now how to make it works again, I was looking for answers I here but I couldn't solve my problem.

When I use the `npm start` in the root folder of the project I get this:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Path\Of\The\Project\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Path\Of\The\Project\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

When I use the `npm start --prefix example` in the root folder of the project I get this:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project-name@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project-name@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

When I use the `npm start` in the example folder I get this:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project-name@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project-name@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Path\_logs\2020-04-09T04_11_04_628Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It is because `npm` relies on there being a `package.json` file in the same folder. If you move to the new folder and try `npm start` again what happens?

Comment: @tycrek I just added that exception inside the question, tells me that "node_modules" is missing